# Aggregate recursive tree structure (parent reference)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We are trying to build a simple CMS that can manage pages and its subPages. And every subPage can also have subPages etc.

The Problem we are currently facing is that we receive a flat tree after the second level and we would have to reorganise the tree with JS.

Is it possible to receive a real tree structure (see "desired output") without the use of JS.

The following tree structure is currently used:

```
[{
    _id: 1,
    name: "top-level",
    parent: null
},{
    _id: 2,
    name: "second-level-a",
    parent: 1 // top-level
},{
    _id: 3,
    name: "second-level-b",
    parent: 1 // top-level
},{
    _id: 4,
    name: "third-level",
    parent: 2 // second-level-a
}]
```

We are currently trying to receive the complete tree via this query:

```
Page.aggregate([
    {
        "$graphLookup": {
            "from": "Page",
            "startWith": "$_id",
            "connectFromField": "_id",
            "connectToField": "parent",
            "as": "subPages",
            "maxDepth": 1,
            "depthField": "depth"
        }
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "options.parent": null
        }
    }
]).exec((err, pages) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
    }
    res.json(pages);
});
```

What we are receiving is something like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: "first-level",
        parent: null,
        subPages: [
            {
                _id: 2,
                name: "second-level-a",
                depth: 0,
                [...]
            },{
                _id: 3,
                name: "second-level-b",
                depth: 0,
                [...]
            },{
                _id: 4,
                name: "third-level",
                depth: 1,
                [...]
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

With this output it's not directly visible where third-level is placed inside the tree. The desired output should look like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: 1,
        name: "first-level",
        parent: null,
        subPages: [
            {
                _id: 2,
                name: "second-level-a",
                depth: 0,
                [...]
                subPages: [
                    {
                        _id: 4,
                        name: "third-level",
                        depth: 1,
                        [...]
                    }
                ]
            },{
                _id: 3,
                name: "second-level-b",
                depth: 0,
                [...]
            }

        ]
    }
]
```

The question is, is this even possible to achieve using MongoDB in combination with mongoose or do we need to sort the result with JS.